# Principal congruence subgroups of $SL(n, \mathbb{Z})$

Tags: gr.group-theory

I want to know whether the principal congruence subgroups of $SL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ are characteristic? please suggest me a reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they are caracteristic.

Let $\rho: GL(n, \mathbb{Z}) \to GL(n, \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$ be reduction mod $m$ and $\Gamma_n(m) := ker(\rho) \cap SL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ be a congruence sugroup.

According to the discussion in [Automorphisms of $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57235/automorphisms-of-sl-n-mathbbz) the automorphisms of $SL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ for $n > 2$ are generated by

- $X \mapsto (X^T)^{-1}$
- $X \mapsto AXA^{-1}, A \in GL(n, \mathbb{Z}).$

Obviously, $\Gamma_n(m)$ is invariant under these automorphisms and thus is characteristic.

In case $n = 2$ there is one more automorphisms of $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ that also leaves $\Gamma_n(m)$ invariant (for a description of this automorphism see the paper of Hua and Reiner mentioned in the link above).

Comment: This is exactly the same answer as @Richard's

Comment: Yes it is. When I was starting to type there was no answer and after I saved mine, I saw Richard's. So I guess there was some overlapping in time. Nevertheless, I decided no to delete my answer since a) it confirms what Richard says he thinks and b) it has some more details about the generators (and the case $n = 2$) that might be interesting for readers who just overflow the question without looking into the mathoverflow link or the Hua-Reiner paper. 

Comment: you are right Ralph

Comment: @Ralph: agreed.

Comment: @Ralph: $\Gamma_n$ is characteristic. but what you said about the automorphism group of $SL(n,\mathbb Z)$ is true for n odd, because for n odd, all automorphisms of $SL(n,\mathbb Z)$ are induced by automorphisms of $GL(n,\mathbb Z)$(Hua-Reiner,theorem.3). Is it true if n even too?



Comment: See this for answer: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/63319/principal-congruence-subgroups-of-sln-z

Comment: @Poove: You're right, Hua-Reiner determine the automorphisms of $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ and the ones of $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ that are induced by an automorphism of $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$. There's a  paper of O'Meara that describes the automorphisms of linear groups over integral domains. Specializing his result to the $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ case yields the same automorphisms as above and shows that each automorphism is induced by one of $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$. But it's rather technical and I hope there's no mistake in my considerations. Details can be found in the link of your comment just ahead. 

Comment: For $n=2$ there are congruence subgroups which are not characteristic, see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/250799).

Answer (score 10):

I think the answer is yes.

See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57235/automorphisms-of-sl-n-mathbbz) for a discussion of $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{Z}))$.  The generators given in the Hua-Reiner paper seem to preserve the principal congruence subgroups.