# are the congruence subgroups $\Gamma(n)$ characteristic inside $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory

For which $n$ is the "principal congruence subgroup" $\Gamma(n)\le \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, the subgroup consisting of matrices congruent to the identity modulo $n$, characteristic?  I.e., for which $n$ is $\Gamma(n)$ stable (as a set) under all automorphisms of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No for $n$ odd, yes for $n$ even.

By a result of [Hua and Reiner](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1951-071-03/S0002-9947-1951-0043847-X/home.html), the automorphism group of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by (1) conjugation by $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ (the matrices with determinant $\pm 1$) and (2) the map $X \mapsto \epsilon(X) \cdot X$ where $\epsilon$ is the unique nontrivial character $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \to \pm 1$. The maps of the form (1) clearly preserve $\Gamma(n)$, so we just need to check the single map $X \mapsto \epsilon(X) \cdot X$.

We can describe $\epsilon$ as follows: $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ acts on the three points of $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{F}_2)$, giving a map $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \to S_3$. Compose this with the sign character $S_3 \to \pm 1$.

If $n$ is odd, then $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \right) \equiv \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \right) \bmod 2$, so $\epsilon \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \right) = -1$. So $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ is in $\Gamma(n)$ but $\epsilon \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \right) \cdot \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \right) = \left( \begin{smallmatrix} -1 & -n \\ 0 & -1 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ is not.

On the other hand, if $n$ is even then $X \equiv \mathrm{Id} \bmod n$ shows that $X$ maps to $e$ in $S_3$, so $\epsilon(X)=1$ and $\epsilon(X) X = X$ for all $X \in \Gamma(n)$.

Comment: Hmm does this imply the same result when you look at the closure of these $\Gamma(n)$'s inside $\widehat{SL_2(\mathbb{Z})}$ and continuous automorphisms?

Comment: Well, the $n$ odd part of the answer is the same, because the automorphism I give extends continuously to the adeles. For n even, I don't know if we get interesting new automorphisms. Dull http://www.jstor.org.proxy.lib.umich.edu/stable/2373578  gives some results on $Out(SL_2(R))$ for $R$ a general commutative ring, which might be useful, but I haven't unpacked them.

Comment: I thought about it a bit more, and the answer is no in more cases for the adelic case. For example, let $p$ be a prime $\equiv 1 \bmod 3$. We have a map $\alpha: \widehat{\Gamma(2p)} \to \mathbb{Z}/(3 \mathbb{Z})$ by $\Gamma(2p) \to SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/3) \cong A_4 \to \mathbb{Z}/(3 \mathbb{Z})$. Let $\zeta$ be a primitive cube root of $1$ in the $p$-adics and let $g \in SL_2(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}})$ be $\zeta \mathrm{Id}$ in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ and $1$; note that $g$ is central. So $X \mapsto g^{\alpha(X)} X$ gives an outer automorphism which doesn't preserve $\widehat{\Gamma(2p)}$.

Comment: I think you left something out. You said "let $g\in SL_2(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}})$ be $\zeta Id$ in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ and 1;"

Did you mean "...and 1 in $\prod_{q\ne p} SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_q)$"?

Comment: Hmm, so your $X\mapsto g^{\alpha(X)}X$ only gives an automorphism of $SL_2(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}})$ right? I don't think this induces a continuous automorphism of $\widehat{SL_2(\mathbb{Z})}$ does it? For example, if you try to replace $g$ with a preimage in $\widehat{SL_2(\mathbb{Z})}$, it won't necessarily by central, right?

Comment: Regarding your first comment: Correct. Regarding your second comment, I need to think about it.

Comment: You are right, I don't know if $g$ lifts to a central element in $\widehat{SL_2(\mathbb{Z})}$.

Comment: ${SL_2(\mathbb Z)}$ is virtually free so $\widehat{SL_2(\mathbb Z)}$ is virtually free and thus center-free.

Comment: Sorry to resurrect this post, but isn't the outer automorphism group actually $\mathbb{Z}/2\times\mathbb{Z}/2$, generated by the $\epsilon$ you describe, and by conjugation by $[[-1,0],[0,1]]$ inside $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$? Your answer is of course still valid, since $\Gamma(n)$ is normal inside $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ as well.

Comment: @Amy You are right! I misread Theorem 2 of Hua and Reiner. Apparently, the word "inner" was in quotes because they didn't actually mean inner.